# Agregar nueva propiedad a objeto guardado en chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, local-storage

el objetivo de esta funcion es agregarle datos a un objeto guardado en `chrome.storage.local`; Estoy implementando esta funcion:

```javascript
/**
 * Set object setting
 * 
 * @param {object} setting 
 */

function addSetting(setting) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ atsu_setting: setting });
}
```

Luego en distintas areas del código intento agregarle mas datos a lo ya existente:

```javascript
chrome.storage.local.set({ atsu_setting: {opened:false} });
chrome.storage.local.set({ atsu_setting: {url:"dato"} });
```

El problema es que estoy monitoreando los datos que están guardando con:

```javascript
setInterval(()=>{ 
    chrome.storage.local.get(atsu)
    .then((setting) => {
        console.log(setting);
    });
}, 10000);
```

pero este solo me muestra lo ultimo guardado; me comentaron que esto se debe a que debo obtener la informacion fusionarla para luego volver a guardarla; esto implica que debo usar asincronía; por lo tanto hacer esto:

```javascript
chrome.storage.local.set({ atsu_setting: {opened:false} });
metodo_siguiente();
```

Tendra un comportamiento no deseado; ya que la asynchronizacion que conozco me pide que implemente algo asi; provocando que en cada lectura de la memoria necesite nestear codigo dentro de un `.then`

```javascript
.then((setting) => {
     metodo_siguiente();
})
```

***como resuelvo/mejoro la Actualización de datos?*** estoy necesitando leer los datos; guardar, los nuevos y retornar estos datos a una variable:

Ejemplo:

```javascript
function udateSetting(objeto){
    chrome.storage.local.get(atsu_setting)
    .then((setting) => {
        //validar que existe:
        if(setting){
            //agregarmos nuevos datos
            setting[Object.keys(objeto)]='dato';
            chrome.storage.local.set(setting);
            return setting;
        }
    });
}

let new_setting = udateSetting({nueva_propiedad:"dato de la propiedad"});

console.log(new_setting);
```

Comment: Asincrónico siempre es mejor, pero ten en cuenta que también puedes usar `chrome.storage.sync.get` que es sincrónico y te devolverá directamente el valor. Creo que esto te convendría dado que de manera asincrónica nunca podrás asegurar que la variable externa al then haya sido escrita.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez que va no me sale...

Comment: Fue mi error, lo siento. `chrome.storage.sync.get` no es sincrónica, si no que sincroniza lo que guardes en cualquier navegador chrome en que el usuario esté logueado. Se me olvidó retirar mi comentario.

Comment: jajajaja ok espero que alguien me apoye en esta pregunta... me ha dado dolor de cabeza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se trabaja con `chrome.storage.local` hasta el momento no se puede realizar actualizaciones directas sobre la informacion con `chrome.storage.local.set(dato);`; debe de hacerse de la siguiente forma:

1. primero recuperarse el dato de `chrome.storage.local.get(dato)`.
2. alterar/actualizar el dato `dato.propiedad = 'nuevo dato';` .
3. volver a insertar el dato a `chrome.storage.local.set(dato);` .

Este seria un ejemplo de como obtener los datos y Guardarlos nuevamente (Actualizado):

```
chrome.storage.local.get("datos")
    .then((setting) => {
        /*Lógica para alterar el dato*/
        setting.propiedad = 'nuevo valor';
        chrome.storage.local.set(setting);
    });
```

Este seria un ejemplo de como se puede alterar un dato o nodo un poco mas complejo y dinámico: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/494185/46896